# Qt - Can't paint over axis values

Tags: c++, qt, plot, qpainter

I'm coding a plot window for real-time input in QtCreator, with data waveforms which writes over themselves in a cyclic manner with a user-specified period.

The actual plotter and the axis initialization are working great, but I'm having some trouble getting the time axis to update at the end of each period. I thought that erasing all data in the label area and re-drawing using the new values would work, but instead the entire axis is erased at the end of the first period. I suspect some problem with my use of QPainter.

First post, go easy on me.

> void T_AxisWidget::initAxis(double window_period) {
>       period = window_period;
>       t_pixmap = QPixmap(size());
>       t_pixmap.fill(Qt::black);
>
> ```
> QPainter painter(&t_pixmap);
> painter.initFrom(this);
> painter.setPen(Qt::red);
> painter.drawLine(0, 0, size().width(), 0);
> painter.drawLine(0, 0, 0, TICK_LENGTH); //always draw first tick at origin
> int tick_interval = size().width()/(num_ticks);
> int remainder = (size().width()%(num_ticks))-1; //pixels to be skipped to cover entire axis
>
> painter.drawText(0, TICK_LENGTH+2, tick_interval/2, size().height()-TICK_LENGTH+2,
>                    Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop,
>                    QString::number(0));
>
> qDebug() << "width = " << size().width();
> qDebug() << "interval = " << size().width()/(num_ticks);
>
> for(int i=tick_interval; i<=size().width()-tick_interval; i+=tick_interval) {
>     if (remainder>0) {
>         ++i; //space ticks an extra pixel apart initially to achieve an even spread
>         --remainder;
>
>         qDebug() << "remainder = " << remainder;
>         qDebug() << "tick = " << i;
>     }
>     painter.drawLine(i, 0, i, TICK_LENGTH);
>     painter.drawText(i-(tick_interval/2), TICK_LENGTH+2, tick_interval, size().height()-TICK_LENGTH+2,
>                        Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignTop,
>                        QString::number((period/(double)num_ticks)*(i/tick_interval)));
>  }
>  painter.drawLine(size().width()-1, 0, size().width()-1, TICK_LENGTH);
>  painter.drawText(size().width()-tick_interval/2, TICK_LENGTH+2, tick_interval/2, size().height()-TICK_LENGTH+2,
>                        Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignTop,
>                        QString::number(period)); }
> ```
>
> void T_AxisWidget::setTValues (int multiplier) {
>       double start = period*multiplier;
>       int tick_interval = period/num_ticks;
>
> ```
> QPainter painter(&t_pixmap);
> painter.initFrom(this);
> painter.setPen(Qt::red);
> QRect eraseblock(0, TICK_LENGTH+2, size().width(), size().height());
> painter.eraseRect(eraseblock);
>
> painter.drawText(0, TICK_LENGTH+2, tick_interval/2, size().height()-TICK_LENGTH+2,
>                Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop,
>                QString::number(start));
>
>
> for(int i=1; i<num_ticks; i++) {
>     painter.drawText(i*tick_interval-(tick_interval/2), TICK_LENGTH+2, tick_interval, size().height()-TICK_LENGTH+2,
>                      Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignTop,
>                      QString::number(start+(i*period/(double)num_ticks)));
> }
> painter.drawText(size().width()-(tick_interval/2), TICK_LENGTH+2, tick_interval/2, size().height()-TICK_LENGTH+2,
>                  Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignTop,
>                  QString::number(period*multiplier));
> ```
>
> }
>
> void T_AxisWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /* event */) {
>       QStylePainter painter(this);
>       painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, t_pixmap); }